# Build errors with Azure DevOps and Blazor Server App

Tags: c#, azure-devops, continuous-integration, blazor

I am trying to add the standard "out-of-the-box" Blazor Server App to Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline.

Every time I try to build the pipeline it throws  this error (in short)

**Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0" were not found.**

Full version:

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1179,5): Error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v5.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

So I am missing a reference to the framework clearly, but how do i add it? One would assume that the standard Blazor Server App would be ready for this job..

[image]

When I created the pipeline I followed these steps:

Step 1 - the starter template

[image]

Step 2 - Adding  .NET Core sdk and dotnet build

[image]

Step 3 - Error in build...

[image]

Any ideas on how to get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Build errors with Azure DevOps and Blazor Server App

Please try to use the hosted agent `windows-2019` instead of the `vs2017-win2016` to build this solution.

That is because the minimum version for .NET 5 RC1 is **VS 16.8 Preview 3**.

[image]

The reference link: [.NET 5.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0).

Comment: Thanks @Leo Liu-MSFT !, I did what you said and it fixed the error and I managed to build the pipeline.